# Explanation of an Easy Proof of Variance of Bernoulli Trials

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I am taking a course in Combinatorics, and I've got two proofs I can use to support the Bernoulli trial variance formula, $\operatorname{var}(X) = np(1-p)$, and I would like to use the one where I don't have to use the binomial formula and the second derivatives.

Here is the explanation from the book:

[image]

Ok, the individual elements are independent.  Got it. Now, when I go to write this out, everything does not quite hang together for me:

$$
\text{Variance is }E(X^2)-E^2(X) \text{.  Additionally, the variance of a family of independent elements }F \text{ is }\sum_{x \in F}{\operatorname{var}(x)}
$$

Now, I am stuck. In this case, $X$ counts the number of successes...so $|X|\ne n$, necessarily.  How do I connect all of this back to $np(1-p)$? (in other words, what is the 'trivial' calculation? (seriously, 'trivial', 'clearly', 'obviously', etc.= bad juju)).

Also, how do I go about showing that $\operatorname{var}(X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n) = \operatorname{var}(X_1) + \dots + \operatorname{var}(X_n)$ ? (although I am pretty sure that proving this would be deeper than is necessary for the class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I was having difficulty with (solved before I understood Variance, Expectation, Indicator Random Variables, and Convolution):

1) The notation.

The family $F$ of $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ represents all the trials.  However, there is a set $X$ implied by the notation $X_n$.  That being said, apparently there is an idiomatic practice of using $X$ to represent both the count of successes in Bernoulli trials, an individual random variable, and $X_i$ to represent an individual Bernoulli trial (where $X$ as the set of all $X_i$ is implied by the specification of the set index notation), so the meaning of $X$ and the notation are both abused.

---

2) The application of the variance formula on a single Bernoulli trial.

The book actually covered my problems, but I had to search around...and after working through the problem and typing this up, I sorted it out.

The definition of the expectation of $X$, the random variable (but really, function) $X: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is:

$$
E(X) = \sum_{x \in S}{\operatorname{X}(x)\operatorname{P}(x)}
$$

And this equation is constrained to a discrete space, and rewritten as a sum:

$$
E(X) = \sum_y{y*\operatorname{prob}(\operatorname{X}(x) = y)}
$$

Next, variance is defined as: $E((X-E(X))^2)$, which is non-trivially shown to be $E(X^2) - E(X)^2$.

Now, I write:

$$
\operatorname{var}(X_i) = E(X_i^2) - E(X_i)^2 = \sum_{y \in X_i}{y^2 * p(X_1(x) = y)} - (\sum_{y\in X_1}{y*p(X_1(x) = y)})^2
$$

Finally, I pull out the terms,

$$
1*p - 1*p^2 = p(1-p)
$$

---

Now I know, because I've cleared up the notation issue, that there will be $n$ of these guys when I apply this formula to the family I fixed at the start...so now, I have $\operatorname{var}(X) = np(1-p)$.

---

---

Here is the solution I settled on After I understood **variance**, **expectation**, **indicator variables** and **convolutions**:

Let $X = {X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}$ be a set of indicator variables. By linearity of Expectation,

$$
\operatorname{E}(X) = \operatorname{E}(X_1) + \operatorname{E}(X_2) + \ldots + \operatorname{E}(X_n)\\
$$

Then I establish that the indicator variables are independent (and this is actually the key step that I wish was clearer, and I knew more about), so:

$$
\operatorname{E}^2(X) = \operatorname{E}^2(X_1) + \ldots\\
$$

---

Next,

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(X) &= \operatorname{E}(X^2) - \operatorname{E}^2(X)\\
\operatorname{E}(X^2) &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\operatorname{E}(X_i X_j)\\
\end{align}
$$

Where $X_i X_j$ equals 1 when $i=j$ and zero otherwise for any given event with probability $p$, so the convolution rewrites as: $np$.

Finally,

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{E}^2(X_i) = n*p^2
$$

So, variance rewrites as:

$$
np - np^2
$$

Comment: Keep in mind that X is a random variable defined as the *sum* of all the independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables in $F$, it is not a set of random variables. Since each of these take on value 1 when a success occurs and 0 when a failure occurs, $X$ really does count the number of successes for all trials.

Comment: @stochasm Right, exactly: X is the count, F is the set. But X_i, in the "set index notation" indicates that X_i is the ith index of *set* X, so it's funky: there is no set X; in programming, this is referred to as "shadowing" the variable: it is fixed twice, once upon setting up all the X_i's, and then later, it is fixed as the sum of all X_i in X:  $X = \sum_{X_i} X_i$ where the notation is specified such that calling $X_i$ implies the existence of set $X$...

Comment: @stochasm simple fix:  Let Y be the set of all Bernoulli trial outcomes.  Then let X be the random variable such that $X = \sum_{Y_i \in Y} {Y_i}$.  Done.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, let us take the formula $$\operatorname{Var}[X_1 + \cdots + X_n] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{Var}[X_1] + \cdots + \operatorname{Var}[X_n]$$ for granted.  Then since $$X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$ where each $X_i$ is IID Bernoulli, namely $$\Pr[X_i = 1] = p, \quad \Pr[X_i = 0] = 1-p,$$ then it is trivial to compute $$\operatorname{E}[X_i] = 0\Pr[X_i = 0] + 1\Pr[X_i = 1] = p,$$ consequently $$\operatorname{Var}[X_i] = (0 - p)^2 \Pr[X_i = 0] + (1 - p)^2 \Pr[X_i = 1] = p^2(1-p) + (1-p)^2 p = p(1-p)(p + 1-p) = p(1-p).$$  Therefore, $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = np(1-p)$$ as claimed.

---

Clarification on the calculation of the variance of a Bernoulli random variable.

Recall that for a discrete random variable with support $X \in \Omega$, $$\operatorname{E}[X]= \sum_{x \in \Omega} x \Pr[X = x];$$ the sum is taken over all of the elementary outcomes of $X$.  If $X$ is Bernoulli, then $\Omega = \{0,1\}$, and the above sum becomes $$\operatorname{E}[X] = 0 \Pr[X = 0] + 1 \Pr[X = 1].$$  Similarly, $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2] = \sum_{x \in \Omega} (x - \operatorname{E}[X])^2 \Pr[X = x].$$  But since we already calculated $\operatorname{E}[X] = p$, we substitute:  $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \sum_{x \in \Omega} (x - p)^2 \Pr[X = x].$$  And again, since $\Omega = \{0,1\}$, this sum becomes $$(0 - p)^2 \Pr[X = 0] + (1 - p)^2 \Pr[X = 1].$$

Comment: Ah, yeah, see, we don't have a formula for an individual trial.  So, $var(x_i)$ is non-trivial.  How is it you are getting the $(0-p)^2 Pr[X_i = 0] + (1 - p)^2 Pr[X_i = 1]$?

Comment: Also, is there any reason why the author would use the notation such that $X_i$ is an index of a family $F$, but $X$ is a scalar after the count of ones in $X$?

Comment: @bordeo: what is your definition of variance?

Comment: @Henry the definition given is:  $E((X-E(X))^2)$ where $E(a)$ is expectation of a, and $X$ is a "random variable," defined as any function $X: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $S$ is a probability space.   I see how the definition mirrors the calculation on line 5, but I don't see how to reason that the definition should be applied to each possible value of X...shouldn't it be a sum?  I guess my question ultimately amounts to: why should I know to do what heropup did on line 5, given my definition of $X_i$ as a bernoulli trial, and the definition of variance?

Comment: @bordeo: For an individual $X_i$ you can have  $(X_i-E(X_i))^2$ taking two possible values, namely $(0-p)^2$ with probability $\Pr[X_i=0]$ or $(1-p)^2$ with probability $\Pr[X_i=1]$.  With your definition of variance, these give $Var(X_i)=p(1-p)$ and so the sum of $n$ independent versions having variance $np(1-p)$

Comment: @Henry and we just "know" to sum them? Honestly, I get it...I'm just struggling with why it isn't either a sum or an integral.  I guess math needs a symbol that means compose everything together, independent of discrete or continuous.

Comment: I'm not following, you say there should be a sum there and then get confused when there is a sum. We "know" to sum them because that's what expectation is. He is computing $E[(X-E(X))^2]$, which is by definition variance. I have a feeling you are getting bogged down by formalism and have lost the plot.

Comment: @stochasm haha, yeah I think you are right about the formalism.

Comment: @stochasm  but also, I think you hit the nail on the head: I needed the definition of the expectation; I was missing that, and I was thrown off by the overuse of X--I didn't have a place to fix $n$ in the write up of my proof...but I posted an answer which clarifies everywhere I was confused (and your right, it was pretty much all wrapped up in the formalism).  But I like to figure it out...I still haven't gotten good at phrasing my question on math stack well enough to really isolate where I am having difficulty...but working through all of this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$$
$$X^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^nX_j\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nX_iX_j$$
$$i=j\implies E(X_iX_j)=E(X_i^2)=E(X_i)=P(X_i=1)=p$$
$$i\ne j\implies E(X_iX_j)=P(X_iX_j=1)=P(X_i=1\text{ and }X_j=1)=P(X_i=1)P(X_j=1)=p^2$$
$$E(X^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nE(X_iX_j)=np+(n^2-n)p^2$$
$$Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2=np+(n^2-n)p^2-(np)^2=np-np^2=np(1-p)$$

Comment: Can you explain how $$\sum_{i=1}\sum_{j=1}E(X_i X_j) = np + (n^2 - n)p^2$$?  Because I get: $ n*p$ because $X$ is an indicator random variable, and $X_i * X_j = 0$ unless $i = j$, and it equals 1.  So $E(X_i X_j) = p$ and the sum is just from 1 to n, since only the diagonal, $ i = j$ matter...So now I have $np$, and then $E^2(X)$ is just $np^2$ after applying linearity of expectation, so I get $np - np^2$, and not all of the other stuff...

Comment: @bordeo What doex $X_i*X_j$ mean? If the $*$ means multiplication, why do you say that $X_iX_j=0$? Since $X_iX_j=1$ when $X_i=1$ and $X_j=1,$ for $i\ne j$ I get$$E(X_iX_j)=P(X_iX_j=1)=P(X_i=1\text{ and }X_j=1)=P(X_i=1)P(X_j=1)=p^2.$$

Comment: $X_iX_j=1$ if both the $i^{\text{th}}$ and $j^{\text{th}}$ trials result in success; since $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent, $P(X_iX_j=1)=p^2.$